# How to remove wpf grid sort arrow after clearing sort descriptions

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I click on a grid header to sort a column and then click a "Reset" button to clear the sort descriptions through its collection view. But the sort arrow icon still persists in the header. How to remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple solution i can think of is

```
foreach (DataGridColumn column in DataGridView.Columns)
{
    column.SortDirection = null;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I came across this question whilst trying to work out how to clear the sort from the grid completely. Thanks to [krishnaaditya] for the answering how to clear the sort arrow from the header.

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(resultsGrid.ItemsSource);
if (view != null && view.SortDescriptions.Count > 0)
{
    view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in resultsGrid.Columns)
    {
        column.SortDirection = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the complete solution. The first answer only removed the sort, but not the arrow from the header.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the above solutions work if you sort a column which uses a converter to display nice data (for example, in one column you have an Enum and you use a converter to display something else). In this situation, the SortDescriptions.Count always remain 0. When you try to reset the sort nothing happens.

Comment: This is because you're messing with the source here, not the actual displayed value.  Try DataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.  That's where the actual values are.  Wrap it in a using with a DeferRefresh for best performance.

Comment: FWIW, if you're using a CustomSort method, SortDescriptions.Count will be zero, but you still want to set the SortDirection values to null to clear the arrows.