# WPF Datagrid: Clear column sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using a WPF Datagrid in my application where columns can be sorted by clicking on the header.

I was wondering if there was any way to clear a column's sorting programatically ?

I tried sorting a column and then clearing `MyDataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions`, but that collection was empty (even though one column was sorted).

I also tried :

```
MyDataGridColumn.SortDirection = null;
```

The problem is that the column indication is gone, but the sorting still occurs when editing a cell and switching rows.

Is there no way to clear a column's sort ?

Edit (for clarity): The problem is that I'd like to allow sorting again if the user re-clicks on the same column header, so setting CanUserSort to false would be problematic, even if it were done in the XAML. In short, what I'm attempting to do, is prevent rows from being ordered once a sorted column has a cell that was modified. I want to force the user to re-click on the header.

Comment: I did not know it would resort when you edit a row.

Comment: @Blam Yep it does. If you select another row, the cell that was edited will have its row sorted.

Comment: Clear from the CollectionView for example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401912/how-to-remove-wpf-grid-sort-arrow-after-clearing-sort-descriptions

Answer (score 19):

Here is what you need:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(grid.ItemsSource);
if (view != null)
{
    view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    foreach (DataGridColumn column in grid.Columns)
    {
        column.SortDirection = null;
    }
}
```

Original source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533076/964053

What I want to know is what was M$ thinking for not putting a ClearSort() method...

Comment: Yeah wondering the same thing. I ultimately used an attached behavior when the ItemSourceProperty changed to clear.

Answer (score 6):

as an extension...

```
    public static  void ClearSort(this DataGrid grid)
    {
        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(grid.ItemsSource);
        view?.SortDescriptions.Clear();

        foreach (var column in grid.Columns)
        {
            column.SortDirection = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `CanUserSort` to `false` for all columns -

```
foreach (var a in MyDataGrid.Columns)
{
    a.CanUserSort = false;
}
```

Comment: Won't this prevent columns from being sorted again ? I'm just looking to remove sorting for a particular column, not disable it for all columns.

Comment: So, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Can't you set for those particular columns in xaml this property to false?

Comment: @RV1987 I think he wants the user to be able to sort all columns manually, but he also wants to programmatically change the sorting in response to user input (say, a button press)

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to allow sorting again if the user re-clicks on the same column header, so setting CanUserSort to false would be problematic, even if it were done in the XAML. In short, what I'm attempting to do, is prevent rows from being ordered once a sorted column has a cell that was modified. I want to force the user to re-click on the header.

@ean5533 Correct :)

Answer (score 0):

In XAML you can turn it off using this code.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Header Name" CanUserSort="False"/>
```

Comment: The question was how to clear it once it is sorted, not how to remove the sort entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my program  (I have a RESET button and use this to clear the sorting on a datagrid).

```
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MY_DATA_GRID.ItemsSource).SortDescriptions.Clear();
```

Works like a charm.

Cheers, Iato

Answer (score -2):

In the XAML code of DataGrid you can add CanUserSortColumns="False". Then noboady would be able to sort any column at rumtime.

Comment: It has already been mentioned in the question that this technique is not suitable.

Comment: @Ren - This is a small code snipet to disable the sorting of DataGridView.

 

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)

{

  dataGridView1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

}

Answer (score -2):

This is a small code snippet to disable the sorting of `DataGridView`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Comment: If you read the question, you will see that this is not what the author wants. He wants to prevent column sorting automatically when users make edits to cells but he wants to leave sorting enabled so that the users can still click a column heading to sort the table if they so wish.