# Turn DataGridColumn sorting off

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, sortdirection

I have a problem with my DataGrid, again... This time: How can I turn off the sorting when I am editing a cell?

For example:

[image]

I add the marked 'A' last and it jumped to the top because the column is sorted. But it should stay at the button. If you sort a settings file (in Visual Studio) it works exactly like I want to. You can try it yourself, here is the same example in VS:
[image]

I tried to reset the `SortDirection`, doesn't work:

```
    private void dgVATINS_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridColumn col in dgVATINS.Columns)
        {
            col.SortDirection = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is for the DataGridView (Windows Forms) not for the DataGrid in WPF

Comment: @reggaeguitar he meant the link you suggested is about Winforms, but he's working with WPF DataGrid.

Comment: this maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401869/wpf-datagrid-clear-column-sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Resets the sorting.
    /// </summary>
    public void ResetSorting()
    {
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgVATINS.ItemsSource); // Gets the default view of the DataGrid
        if (view != null && view.SortDescriptions.Count > 0)
        {
            view.SortDescriptions.Clear(); // Clears the sorting

            foreach (DataGridColumn column in dgVATINS.Columns)
            {
                column.SortDirection = null;
            };
        }
    }
```

And add an event handler to the `CollectionChanged` event from the `ObservableCollection<T>`

```
 void VATINS_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    ResetSorting();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Helper.SetGridViewSortState(this.dgv, DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
Please try this

Comment: Its for a DataGirdView, I am looking for a solution for a DataGrid (in WPF)